# Xcode 7.2: Impossible to run unit tests on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I have a complex enough application with some tests which as far as I remember used to run and give output whether they were successful or not.

I did not run the tests every time I changed the code (not very proud of it) but now after some months after the last test run, I cannot seem to run the tests on device. Xcode has been updated at least 2 times since then.

Before giving you the 3 different errors I get each time I run the tests (yes, it is that bad), I have to mention that I get nearly the same behavior with a fresh, minimal test app I created to see what is going on. The tests I run in that case are also minimal, like:

```
assetEqualsObjects(@"a", @"b").
```

Every time I run the test, I get no output apart from the "success" or "failed" icon, which is not consistent at all, as it passes or fail the same test depending on its whims.

"sometimes" i get this popup error:

> The run destination .... is not valid for Testing the scheme
>   'TestApplication'.

"some other times" i get the following popup:

> process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app

and finally, sometimes I get an error in the main loop in this line:

```
 return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I would go deeper to my app and see what I m doing wrong, but I luckily created a minimal app and i get the same behavior.

i would like that someone if not give a solution, at least try to help to isolate the error...

UPDATE: my primary development device is an iPhone 6s, but I tried to reproduce the problem on an iPhone 6 and and could not, everything works as it should. So the problem may be at the phone...

Comment: What about on simulator?

Comment: the sample app tests run on simulator (I even get a small icon next to them with an X or a tick ) and I get the test output on the logging panel.

Comment: Is that good enough, or do need to run performance tests?

Comment: no of course it is not :-) I may need to run performance tests in the future and I currently have my libraries are only built for iOS-devices. But look at my update over, the problem seems to be the phone and not Xcode...

Comment: Xcode is such a poorly maintained IDE. I have so many issues when it comes to writing UI tests and XCTests..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem appears to be solved after rebooting the device.
When the problem first arose, I rebooted the Mac and Xcode but this did not help, so my guess was that it was not deterministic. I was proved wrong...

Comment: so I normally consider rebooting the device answers bs, however I have an Iphone 6s and had the same problems and a reboot fixed it for me too